# How to find out number of hospitals near a GPS coordinate?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to count number of hospitals in an area. GPS coordinates are given and I want to find out how many hospital exits in certain meters radius.

There is no restriction or limitation on use of technology type. It could be Java, google-maps-apis, android or even any combinations of these technologies.

Comment: Use this API : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=LatitudeValue,LangitudeValue&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=APIKEY'

Comment: @Stallion This will plot it on a map. I need to collect hopsital count in database.

Comment: The API will not plot . It will give response data. You need to iterate and find out the result.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to execute it and collect data, will it be JSON?

Answer (score 1):

if coordinates of hospitals are given, you can calculate distance between your and hospitals coordinates using this

```
float[] distance = new float[2];

Location.distanceBetween( marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude,
    circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

if( distance[0] > circle.getRadius()  ){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=eng)

Comment: This seems helpful. Coordinates can be collected. I'll give it a try.